# Collecting the first digit of 1000 random numbers and putting each 9 digits into frequency

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created 1000 random numbers down a spreadsheet (A1,A1000), But i would like to find the amount of times each first digit comes up.

example

```
12345
1354
2849
```

Digit 1 comes up twice,
Digit 2 comes up once
(in spreadsheet terms)

Comment: You answer is likely a combination of the LEFT and COUNTIF functions.  LEFT(A1,1) will get you the first digit of A1.  COUNTIF will count all the cells in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)
```

and copy down

In **C1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$1000,ROW())
```

and copy down thru **C9**

Comment: Exactly what I would suggest.

Comment: @Trenin  Might be a more compact approach using **array formulas** but what the heck: cells are cheap!

Answer (score 0):

Directly without a helping column, in `B1:B9`

`=SUMPRODUCT(--((LEFT($A$1:$A$1000,1)+0)=ROW())*1)`